# MooTools classes and `this` in delayed function calls

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have difficulties with using the `this` keyword in a MooTools (1.3) class.  The constructor assigns a value to an attribute, and a subsequently run method displays this value in an `alert` popup.  If I want to run this method delayed (using `myfunction.delay(…)`) the popup displays `undefined`.

```
var MyClass = new Class({   
    initialize: function() {
        this.x = 13;
    },               
    run: function() {
        alert(this.x);
    }
});
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var m = new MyClass();
    m.run();              // ``13''
    m.run.delay(2000);    // ``undefined''
});
```

After fiddling around, I managed to find the following solution:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    var m = new MyClass();
    (function() { m.run() }).delay(2000);    // ``13''
});
```

Still, I would like to understand what’s happening here, and why simply calling `m.run.delay(…)` doesn’t do the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we call `delay` on a function, that function will be executed in the context of the global object (usually `window`). The solution is to wrap it inside another function and capture the object `m` in the closure.

An easier way to doing this is to use the [`bind` parameter](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3adelay) in the call to `delay`. The bind parameter specifies what the `this` value should refer to inside the function when it is invoked.

```
m.run.delay(2000, m);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a function as `m.run()` the `this` keyword will refer to the base object `m`. `Function.prototype.delay` however probably uses `setTimeout` to invoke your delayed function.

```
Function.prototype.delay = function(ms) {
  setTimeout(this, ms);
}
```

The problem with this form is that `setTimeout` will invoke your function without the base object reference, so `this` will refer to the global object (~ *window*).

The solution is to pass the object of invocation to [`delay`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Function%3adelay) explicitly.

```
/**
 * delay - (number) The duration to wait (in milliseconds).
 * bind  - (object, optional) The object that the "this" of the function
 *          will refer to.
 * args  - (mixed, optional) The arguments passed (must be an array if the 
 *          arguments are greater than one).
 */
m.run.delay(2000, m);
```

Comment: A stranger passed by, and because he couldn't understand a single bit of the issue being adressed here, he started to play with the arrows that change color when you click them. "At least there's something interesting in this site." - he thought.

Comment: heh, upvoted to cancel that :) nothing wrong with this answer cept for it's a dupe / hardly improving of anurag's reply, perhaps downvote was due to that.

Comment: My answer is more complete as it describes `why` the function is invoked with the global object as `this`. Also @Anurag states that window is THE global object, which is **false**.

Comment: no, he said window __usually__ is the global object. also, in mootools the delay prototype does not quite work like in the simplified example that you posted (as i am sure you already know) - https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/Function.js#L59 - which can be misleading w/o the **actual** code.

Comment: window is a **host object** referencing the global object. That's not the same. I've never stated the example is from MooTools. I've only outlined the type of invocation inside delay (via `setTimeout`), which is correct. It matters because it calls your object like `a = obj.method; a();`, and this is why the object of invocation (`this`) wont refer to the base object. There's nothing misleading if you understand what the issue is. I'm not here to copycat others code, blindly drop in links, or google search pages as so many people do.

Comment: `There's nothing misleading if you understand what the issue is` - clearly helpful if you know it - then again, he would not have asked it if he did. come on, you are just nitpicking here, nobody is disputing your knowledge - it was merely a suggestion as to why your answer may have been downvoted.